# Refreshing a folder that doesn't exist in the file system

Tags: winapi, refresh, intptr, shell-extensions, change-notification

In my shell extension I have folders that don't actually exist in the file system, but only appear so to the user.

When the content of those folders is changed, I want to refresh them, and currently I do it in the same method I do for regular folders:

```
Win32.SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_UPDATEDIR, SHCNF_IDLIST | SHCNF_FLUSH, PIDL, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Whereas `PIDL` is a list of shell folders IDs, as required by `SHCNF_IDLIST`.

The problem is that explorer doesn't handle my non existing folders. Instead of refreshing them, it sends me back to the root folder.

I know that I construct the `PIDL` correctly since this mechanism works for existing folders, as previously mentioned.

How can I override the handler to `SHChangeNotify`? Or is there a better way for calling refresh?

**Edit:**

How my `PIDL` is generated:

```
    IntPtr GetPIDL(IFolderItem target)
    {
        Stack stack = new Stack(5);
        IntPtr data = IntPtr.Zero;

        byte[] rootPIDL = null;

        IFolderItem curr = target;
        while (curr != null)
        {
            if (curr.rootPIDL != null)
            {
                rootPIDL = curr.rootPIDL;
            }
            else
            {
                data = curr.SerializeInt();
                stack.Push(data);
            }

            curr = curr.ParentFolder;
        }

        if (rootPIDL == null && stack.Count == 0)
            return IntPtr.Zero;

        object[] x = stack.ToArray();

        IntPtr[] pidls = null;

        int count = stack.Count;
        if (count > 0)
        {
            pidls = new IntPtr[stack.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                pidls[i] = (IntPtr)stack.Pop();
            }
        }

        return CreatePIDL(rootPIDL, pidls);
    }
```

My `CreatePIDL` implementation:

```
        internal unsafe static IntPtr CreatePIDL(byte[] rootPIDL,IntPtr[] pidls)
        {
            int headerSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(ushort));
            int totalSize = headerSize;
            if (rootPIDL != null)
                totalSize += rootPIDL.Length - headerSize;

            if (pidls!=null && pidls.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (IntPtr data in pidls)
                {
                    totalSize += PIDLSize(data);
                }
            }

            IntPtr ret = PIDLAlloc(totalSize);
            IntPtr currPos = ret;

            if(rootPIDL!=null)
            {
                Marshal.Copy(rootPIDL, 0, currPos, rootLPIFQ.Length - headerSize);
                currPos = Win32.AdvancePtr(currPos, rootLPIFQ.Length - headerSize);
            }

            if (pidls != null && pidls.Length>0)
            {
                foreach (IntPtr data in pidls)
                {
                    int dataLength = PIDLSize(data);
                    Win32.CopyMemory(currPos, data, dataLength);
                    currPos = Win32.AdvancePtr(currPos, dataLength);
                }
           }
           Marshal.WriteInt16(currPos, (short)0);

            return ret;
        }

        internal static unsafe int PIDLSize(IntPtr ptr)
        {
            return (int) (*((ushort*)ptr));
        }

        internal unsafe static IntPtr PIDLAlloc(int size)
        {
            IntPtr ret = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(size);
            if (ret == IntPtr.Zero)
                throw new OutOfMemoryException();

            return ret;
        }
```

Comment: The documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762118%28v=vs.85%29.aspx states that when calling SHCNE_UPDATEDIR the directory should exist.

Comment: Something wrong with your code. I use SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_UPDATEDIR, SHCNF_IDLIST) for updating my virtual namespace folders and it works.  Could you explain term "PIDL is a list of shell folders IDs"?

Comment: @DenisAnisimov My goal is to refresh a given folder. Should my list contain only the folder I want to refresh? Currently I'm returning a list of PIDLs from the current directory and through its parent up to the root. To get the PIDL of a given folder item (which implements IShellFolder and IShellFolder2) I'm simply using the Marshal class.

Comment: List must contain a chain of PIDL from root to your folder. How do you create your PIDL?

Comment: @DenisAnisimov I create my `PIDL` by iterating over the folders and their parents until I reach the root folder. For each folder along the way, I serialize it to an `IntPtr ` and add it to an array. The order of the array is so that my current folder is the last and the root folder is the first. At the end, I'm creating a single `PIDL` from the root data and from the array.

Comment: It will be better if you show your code.

Comment: @DenisAnisimov I edit my question with some relevant code. Please let me know if you are interested in seeing the code of `CreatePIDL` as well. I'm not sharing it because I would rather share as less as I can, this code is sensitive.

Comment: That the framework do you use? Is there any documentation about IFolderItem?

Comment: @DenisAnisimov I implement `IFolderItem` myself based on some enterprise code. Which area do you think could be relevant? `rootPIDL ` property?

Comment: @DenisAnisimov I initialize `rootPIDL` using the value given to me by `IPersistFolder.Initialize()`. Do you think the problem could be at `CreatePIDL()`?

Comment: Could you show CreatePIDL function?

Comment: @DenisAnisimov Added, please take a look

Comment: I don`t know C# so your code breaks my brain :) What "curr.SerializeInt" do? What the information "data" variable stores after "curr.SerializeInt"?

Comment: `SerializeInt` is a function that I implement as part of `IFolderItem`. In short, it simply serializes the folder representation to a byte array. It is used by the shell through many of the API calls, it didn't give me any problems in other locations. The implementation is rather cumbersome. How would you expect it to work?

Comment: Are there 2 bytes with size of array in the beginning of array created by SerializeInt?

Comment: @DenisAnisimov Yes, I do allocate two extra bytes, chosen randomly according to the documentation I have

Comment: Randomly? What do you mean? 2 bytes must contain size of data including this 2 bytes.

Comment: Oh yes, I write two bytes that contains the size including the extra bytes, and then two random bytes as signature

Comment: rootPIDL is pointer? When you initialize rootPIDL using the value given to you by IPersistFolder.Initialize do you copy whole value or you just set rootPIDL to value? What is rootLPIFQ? Don`t see any definition. And it looks totalSize does not include 2 bytes stored by Marshal.WriteInt16(currPos, (short)0)

Comment: @DenisAnisimov It is indeed a pointer. I'm using Marshal.Copy() to copy the IntPtr given to me by Initialize(). rootLPIFQ==rootPIDL, an error in the transcript :) Hmmm you are right regarding the totalSize. Does seems strange, I'll take another look into it

Comment: I was wrong, totalSize includes 2 additional bytes at the end of PIDL. And now I don`t see any error in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround. It is not pretty nor optimal, yet it works well.

Instead of calling the notify with `SHCNE_UPDATEDIR`, I'm executing all three of the following notifiers in sequence:

```
Win32.SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_MKDIR, SHCNF_IDLIST | SHCNF_FLUSH, PIDL, IntPtr.Zero);
Win32.SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_CREATE, SHCNF_IDLIST | SHCNF_FLUSH, PIDL, IntPtr.Zero);
Win32.SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, SHCNF_IDLIST | SHCNF_FLUSH, PIDL, IntPtr.Zero);
```